# OnclickItem RecycleView

Tags: java, android

in my recycleview adapter i have this class and i want to get text from my recycleview but when i cliked in items nothing happen i think i should call methode in my fragment but i don't know how !

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView myTextView;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        myTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comicName);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mClickListener != null)
            {
                mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
            Toast.makeText(ApplicationContextProvider.getContext(),getItem(getAdapterPosition()),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

// parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own call back method for recycleritemclick and then register that callback inside your fragme t and parse the whatever data you want via that callback. Refer to following answer for code and other details.
[Refer to this answer for implementation details.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30487700/5250973)

Comment: Bro, you instanciate the onClickListener inside the activity and pass reference to recyclerview constructor. It's null, that's why it's printing outside of the if statement.