# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String[] cannot be cast to java.util.List

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I've read some other questions on this topic , but my case is different as it encompasses three java classes.

First I've an adapter for recycler view which is sending me the name of the course clicked through an `intent` in `onClick()`.

`CustomAdapter.java`:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

import static androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<String> data;
    private List<Integer> d2;
    private Context c;
    public CustomAdapter (Context c , List<String> data,List<Integer> data2){
        this.c = c;
        this.data = data;
        this.d2 = data2;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View rowItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_view, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(rowItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(this.data.get(position));
        holder.tv2.setText(Integer.toString(this.d2.get(position)));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView textView,tv2;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            this.textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
            this.tv2 = view.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
// I'm passing the name of the course which the user clicked at to CourseList.java
            Intent i = new Intent(c, CourseList.class);
            i.putExtra("course",textView.getText().toString());
            c.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Just to reiterate , here is the intent:

```
  @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
// I'm passing the name of the course which the user clicked at to CourseList.java
            Intent i = new Intent(c, CourseList.class);
            i.putExtra("course",textView.getText().toString());
            c.startActivity(i);
        }
```

In `CourseList.java`, I want to show the topics related to the clicked course. So, making use of `recyclerview` and storing the topics related to each course (`List<String>`) in a `HashMap<String,String[]>`.

`CourseList.java`:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class CourseList extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle saved){
        super.onCreate(saved);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reg);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        HashMap courses = new HashMap<String,String[]>();
        courses.put("Negotiation",new String[]{"Common ground", "Carpet"});
        courses.put("Pyschology",new String[]{"Happy", "No"});
        courses.put("Joke",new String[]{"Map", "Sarcasm"});
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        String a = extras.getString("course");
        List<String> b = (List<String>) courses.get(a);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new CourseAdapter(CourseList.this, b));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));


    }
}
```

My HashMap `courses.get()` returns a `java.lang.Object` but the constructor of `CourseAdapter.java` requires a `java.util.List<java.lang.String>`.
So, I'm typecasting at this line:

```
List<String> b = (List<String>) courses.get(a);
```

But my app is crashing with the runtime error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String[] cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

Here is `CourseAdapter.java` (Adapter for `CourseList.java`):

`CourseAdapter.java`:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

import static androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity;

public class CourseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CourseAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<String> data;
    private Context c;
    public CourseAdapter (Context c , List<String> data){
        this.c = c;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public CourseAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View rowItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_view, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(rowItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CourseAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(this.data.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView textView,tv2;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            this.textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(c, RegistrationActivity.class);
            c.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a bad approach, why are you passing in context and handling click listeners inside of your recycler ? you should rather be using callback methods to move this logic out, back into your activity or fragment

Comment: @a_local_nobody how will I assign clickListeners  for every element outside my recycler view? I think it will be too complicated.

Comment: `I think it will be too complicated` what's normal for the spider is chaos for the fly :)  lots of examples online for doing it, it's the better approach to follow , your approach doesn't make this recycler reusable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487700/recyclerview-onitemclicked-callback

Comment: Just to comment on the problem you have asked about (and not the whole approach). You are invoking `courses.get(a)` which will return a `String[]` and you are trying to cast it as a `List<String>`. You can't just cast it as a `List<String>` (which is what the exception says) and hope it works. Either have `List<String>` in your `courses` map or convert the result of the get.

Comment: @KenAdams You can just get the context from the view parameter `view.getContext()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A type safe `courses` looks like:

```
Map<String, String[]> courses = new HashMap<>();
```

If you do not use parameters `<>` then the compiler switches off the generic typing, as ancient pre-generics java style.

As `courses.get(a)` returns a `String[]`, you can shovel them into the list as:

```
List<String> b = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(b, courses.get(a));
```

Alternatively and shorter, but the list wraps the array, so you cannot add/remove, and set will alter the array (I understood you just want to iterate over it):

```
List<String> b = Arrays.asList(courses.get(a));
```

This also shows why you should use interfaces (List, Map) instead of implementing classes (ArrayList, HashMap) - as you did with `HashMap` -. as `asList` returns just a `List<String>`.

Comment: "Alternatively and shorter:" but slightly different, insofar as changes to the second `b` will change the array stored in the map, whereas changes to the first `b` would not (amongst other differences).

Answer (score 1):

... how can you NOT see it!?

```
    HashMap courses = new HashMap<String,String[]>();
    List<String> b = (List<String>) courses.get(a);
```

Let me show some detail what this does:

```
    HashMap courses = new HashMap<String,String[]>();
    String[] temp = courses.get(a);
    List<String> b = (List<String>) temp;
```

Now why does a cast from `String[]` to `List<String>` fail? Because one is a List, and the other one is an Array.

Either use

```
    HashMap<String,List<String>> courses = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> b = courses.get(a);
```

or do

```
    HashMap<String,String[]> courses = new HashMap<>();
    String[] b =  courses.get(a);
```

, no casting necessary.

Comment: courses.get(a) is returning a `java.lang.Object`. So for your first suggestion , I'm getting this error: `Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.Object', required: 'java.util.List<java.lang.String>'`. Similar error for the second one as well.

Comment: The most important thing to point out is that `HashMap courses` is a [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). If it was correctly declared as `HashMap<String, String[]> courses`, the code would simply not compile on the line where it is currently failing at runtime, because casting from a `String[]` to a `List<String>` is not allowed.

Comment: @KenAdams "I'm getting this error" because you're using raw types.

Comment: Oh damn. I updated my code to properly reflect what I was suggesting. Thanx for the hints. I simply missed it when copying the code together. An NO, `courses.get(a)` will NOT return an `Object`. It is just your use of a raw type that will lead to that, forcing the compiler to assume it's an `Object`, because it cannot guarantee anything else. In any case, it will return what was stored in it. I updated my answer to show how it is done.